# Get an element of an array no matter the size of the index

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

It exists some library with a function that allow me to do something like the code example I post bellow? I search without success and Lodash doesn't have such a method. Maybe it'll be nice to add it to their API. Thanks in advance.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
functionX(array,  6) === 2;
functionX(array, -1) === 5;
functionX(array, -7) === 4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want a library function, when you can try something like

```
function functionX(array, index) {
    index = index % array.length;
    return index >= 0 ? array[index] : array[array.length + index]
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1ufpqhtd/)

Comment: Yeah, it was an stupid question. Seems it's late and I need to sleep... Anyway, thanks for the quick answer